# SwingWorker still causing non-responsive UI during computation

Tags: java, neural-network

I am writing a UI that starts a `SwingWorker` to call some outside library functions, specifically from the [neuroph library](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/), to simulate neural networks. In the `SwingWorker` I either generate a population of `Genome`s or I run some population through a genetic algorithm to find the best `Genome`s.

The worker generates an initial population and returns fast enough that I can't tell if the calls to `SwingWorker.process` complete before the `SwingWorker` calls `SwingWorker.done`. Though running the population through the genetic algorithm causes the UI to freeze until it has completed (currently not allowing me to test any further). No `.process` messages are sent to the UI when the genetic algorithm logic is used, until it completes.

I also noticed that the library writes to the standard output for each `LearningEvent` generated by the instantiated neural network. So when the `SwingWorker` is processing the population of neural networks "tons" (3 lines per network learning and testing) of output is generated. *Could this be causing the backup of `.process` calls back to the UI?*

*Is there a way to force a `SwingWorker` to wait until all of its `.process` messages have been sent and received by the UI?*

Here is a code sample of the `SwingWorker`

```
public class MLPEnvironment extends SwingWorker<Boolean, String>
{
    int gensRan = 0;
    boolean usingGA;
    DataSet envData;
    MainView mainView;
    LinkedList<Genome> population;
    EnvironmentParameters envParms;

    public MLPEnvironment(MainView inView, EnvironmentParameters inParms, LinkedList<Genome> inPop, DataSet inData)
    {
        envData = inData;
        mainView = inView;
        envParms = inParms;
        population = inPop;
        usingGA = envParms.evolveAtleastOneParameter();
    }

    // Main logic of worker
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        Boolean retVal = Boolean.TRUE;

        // Generate a initial population if this flag is set
        if(envParms.m_bGenerateInitPop)
        {
            newStatus("> Generating initial population...");
            generateInitialPopulation();
        }

        // If we are not just generating a population, but running the GA
        if(!envParms.m_bOnlyGenInitPop)
        {
            newStatus("> Running evolution on population...");
            startBigBang();
            newStatus("- Number of generations ran: " + gensRan);
        }
        // Otherwise just push the initial population to the UI for the user to see
        else
        {
            newStatus("> Pushing population to UI...");
            newStatus("ClearTable");
            for(int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++)
            {
                Genome curGen = population.get(i);
                String layerWidths = "";
                for(int j = 0; j < curGen.getLayerWidths().size(); j++)
                {
                    layerWidths += curGen.getLayerWidths().get(j).toString();
                    if(j != curGen.getLayerWidths().size()-1)
                        layerWidths += "-";
                }
                newStatus("NewRow" + GenomeFitnessResults.getResultsCSV(curGen) + curGen.getTFType() + "," + curGen.getLayerWidths().size() + "," + layerWidths + ",");
            }
            newStatus("- Done displaying initial population");
        }
        newStatus("Environment worker thread finished");

        return retVal;
    }

    // Generate the initial population
    private void generateInitialPopulation()
    {
        newStatus("  Initial population size: " + envParms.m_iInitPopSize);
        newStatus("  DataInSize: " + envData.getInputSize() + " DataOutSize: " + envData.getOutputSize());
        newStatus("  Trans: " + envParms.m_bEvolveTransferFunction + " Count: " + envParms.m_bEvolveHiddenLayerCount + " Widths: " + envParms.m_bEvolveHiddenLayerWidth);

        for(int i = 0; i < envParms.m_iInitPopSize; i++)
        {
            population.add(Genome.getGenomeFromParms(envParms));
        }
        newStatus("- Finished generating initial population");
    }

    // The start of the GA, the beininng of the networks "universe"
    private void startBigBang()
    {
        newStatus("  Using genetic algorithm: " + usingGA);
        newStatus("  Evaluating initial population...");
        population = Genome.evaluate(population, envData, envParms);
        newStatus("  Done evaluating initial population");

        if(usingGA)
        {
            newStatus("  > Starting genetic algorithm...");
            for(int i = 0; i < envParms.m_iNumGenerations; i++)
            {
                gensRan++;
                newStatus("    Generation: " + gensRan);
                population = Genome.select(population, envParms);
                population = Genome.crossOver(population, envParms);
                population = Genome.mutate(population, envParms);
                population = Genome.evaluate(population, envData, envParms);
            }
            newStatus("  - Genetic algorithm terminated");
        }

        newStatus("- Done running algorithm");
    }

    // Clean-up and closure after main process
    @Override
    protected void done() 
    {
        try 
        { 
            final Boolean retVal = get();
            mainView.environmentRunComplete(retVal, population);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            // Not sure who I can tell... 
            System.out.println("DC: InterruptedException");
            mainView.environmentRunComplete(Boolean.FALSE, null);
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException ex) 
        {
            // Not sure who I can tell... 
            System.out.println("DC: ExecutionException");
            mainView.environmentRunComplete(Boolean.FALSE, null);
        } 
    }


    // These are used to write updates to the main view
    private void newStatus(String arg)
    {
        publish(arg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> list) 
    {
        list.stream().forEach((line) -> { mainView.newStatusLine(line); });
    }
}
```

EDIT: So another way to put it.

I understand that

```
publish("a");
publish("b", "c");
publish("d", "e", "f");
```

Might actually result in

```
process("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

being called. Is there any defined interval when the process "batches" go to the UI? When I start the swing worker with a button click the UI becomes unresponsive, but the library prints system output lines, then once all the swingworker computation is done I then see all of the calls the `newStatus` in the UI.

So I know that the worker is doing some intense work, but why are all calls to `newStatus` over the few seconds it takes to do its work batched into a single publish after all work is complete? Shouldn't some publish calls get sent to the UI prior and before an intensive task is performed?

If anything, shouldn't the UI remain responsive because none of the messages are being shown as the swing worker is working?

Comment: *"Is there a way to force a SwingWorker to wait until all of its .process messages have been sent and received by the UI?"* - No, that's kind of the point.  You could use `Thread.yield` or `Thread.sleep` within the `doInBackground` method to try and reduce the overhead a little...

Comment: I made an edit with some clarification as to what I mean. I guess even if the `process` messages are not making it until the worker completes, why would the UI still remain unresponsive until it does?

Comment: *"over the few seconds it takes to do its work batched into a single publish after all work is complete"* - This is how `SwingWorker` works, it's kind of waiting for a "low" in the you worker to push the values passed to `publish` over to the EDT.  If you add a `Thread.yield` or even a small `Thread.sleep` in your processing, you will find more values get pushed to the `process` method...

Comment: I guess my issue was calling my `SwingWorker` with `.run()` instead of `execute()`. But I also implemented a nice progress bar and now that it works I can even watch the algorithm run it real time. Thanks for the help yet again @MadProgrammer!

Comment: Yeah, that would be a problem, nice catch.  Add it as an answer and accept it when you can so the question can be closed ;)

Comment: Actually this raises a new question I can't find the answer to, what is the difference between run and execute? The same between invokeLater and off the EDT?

Comment: Okay, after some digging, `SwingWorker#run`, basically, in a round-about way, will just call `doInBackground` from within the same thread context that it is called, just like calling `Thread#run`.  `SwingWorker@execute` schedules the execution of the `doInBackground` into another thread context (out of the EDT) which is managed by it's own (`SwingWorker`) internal `ExecutorService`